# 2 identical "Camera" slideshows. One works, one acts funny

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I am working on a VERY old web page that was using JAVA code to display 2 identical slideshows. I have been tasked with updating this to jQuery Camera Plugin.

I have used the plugin before and this seems very straight-forward, however the one slideshow on the right is acting very unusual. The image will transition in and then simply disappear. I am wondering if anyone can shed some light on why this might be happening.

**NOTE** *Please forgive the ridiculous outdated HTML and all of the inline CSS. It is not my code!! :(*

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('.camera_wrap').camera({
      pagination: false,
      thumbnails: false,
      navigation: false,
      playPause: false,
      time: 3000,
      loader: 'none'
    });
  });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <table style="width:800px;height:220px;margin:0 auto;" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:266px">

                    <div class="camera_wrap" id="cw1" style="width:266px;height:185px;">
                        <div data-src="../JPEGS/3.jpg"></div>
                        <div data-src="../JPEGS/4.jpg"></div>
                        <div data-src="../JPEGS/5.jpg"></div>
                        <div data-src="../JPEGS/6.jpg"></div>
                        <div data-src="../JPEGS/7.jpg"></div>
                        <div data-src="../JPEGS/11a.jpg"></div>
                        <div data-src="../JPEGS/14.jpg"></div>
                    </div>


            </td>
            <td style="width:268px;text-align:center;" valign="middle">
                <b><font color="#FFFFCC" face="Arial Black" size=
                "5"><i>ENGINEERING</i></font></b>
                <p><b><font color="#FFFFCC" face="Arial Black" size=
                "5"><i>ARCHITECTURE</i></font></b></p>
                <p><b><font color="#FFFFCC" face="Arial Black" size=
                "5"><i>SURVEYING</i></font></b></p>
                <p><b><font color="#FFFFCC" face="Arial Black" size=
                "5"><i>PLANNING</i></font></b></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width:266px">

                    <div class="camera_wrap" id="cw2" style="width:266px;height:185px;">
                        <div data-src="../JPEGS/3.jpg"></div>
                        <div data-src="../JPEGS/4.jpg"></div>
                        <div data-src="../JPEGS/5.jpg"></div>
                        <div data-src="../JPEGS/6.jpg"></div>
                        <div data-src="../JPEGS/7.jpg"></div>
                        <div data-src="../JPEGS/11a.jpg"></div>
                        <div data-src="../JPEGS/14.jpg"></div>
                    </div>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to seperate the slideshows, I can see you have different id cw1 and cw2, then refer by

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#cw1').camera({
      pagination: false,
      thumbnails: false,
      navigation: false,
      playPause: false,
      time: 3000,
      loader: 'none'
    });
$('#cw2').camera({
      pagination: false,
      thumbnails: false,
      navigation: false,
      playPause: false,
      time: 3000,
      loader: 'none'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I ended up usign `.each()` and it works great. Thanks to you both.